# Custom implementation of StatusAggregator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

After migration to Spring Boot 2.3.0 I need to create a custom implementation of StatusAggregator.
However, I don't know exactly how to do it properly after when the HealthAggregator is deprecated. I've got several external systems and I check their availability and in the previous version I had method `Health aggregate(Map<String, Health> healths)` but now it's `Status getAggregateStatus(Set<Status> statuses)` from interface StatusAggregator where as an argument it has Set of Statuses. I need to recognize from with system Status object comes, so during creation Health, I use the approach where I create Status with description, something like this:
`Health.status(new Status((Status.DOWN.getCode(), "TEST_SYSTEM")).build())`
Then I want to recognize it in method `Status getAggregateStatus(Set<Status> statuses)` by this description however when I go to Status.class and check equals it not include description field.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return obj instanceof Status ? ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(this.code, ((Status)obj).code) : false;
        }
    }
```

so `Set<Status>` will return only Statuses with different code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also looking to do something similar and did not find a way to identify the component sending the status. I defined custom health indicators for each API and checked the dependencies for external APIs within those individual health indicators. For custom health indicator, implement the health method in the HealthIndicator and annotate with 'component' to register in the application context as explained in the documentation.